# Растянуть изображение на половину блока

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть картинка и блок с классом `image` и внутри картинка:

```html
<div class="image" style="float: right;">
   <img src="./Img/calendarImage1.png" alt="calendarImage1">
</div>
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, как растянуть эту картинку на половину страницы в ширину?

Comment: Ширине img задать половину ширины дива? И потом просто прижать к нужному краю

Comment: @Aqua Попробовал, картинка просто перемещается

Comment: @Aqua Все, у меня получилось, я удалил тег `img`, а блоку `div` в css файл записал следующее `background: url("../Img/calendarImage1.png") right / cover;` и `width: 50%;`. Так что огромное спасибо!

Comment: Если вы нашли ответ, напишите его в ответ. Что б другие, у кого возникнет такой же вопрос, нашли его сразу. Рад что у вас получилось!

Comment: @Aqua Я надеялся, что это сделаете вы, дело в том, что если написать свой ответ его долго нельзя принять. Так что я вкурсе это золотого правила.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть пара вариантов. Разметка общая:

```
<div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Vel quasi, alias, odio suscipit a quibusdam, enim omnis eveniet itaque quam sed accusantium assumenda ea consectetur libero dolores illo optio reprehenderit! Suscipit nisi aut reprehenderit ullam neque impedit doloremque dignissimos facilis distinctio ipsam! Ipsam, enim?</p>
    <img src="test.jpg" alt="picture">
</div>
```

Первый вариант

```
.container {
    display: flex;
}
img {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Второй вариант

```
.container {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
img {
     width: 100%;
}
```